# No resource found that matches the given name attr "colorPrimary"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having a hard time compiling my Android App in Xamarin Studio. The error that comes up is as follows:

> No resource found that matches the given name attr "colorPrimary"

Which refers to my styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <!--item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item-->
        <!--item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item-->
    </style>
</resources>
```

The usual advice found online is to set the SDK version to 21 or higher. But I already tried that:

- Set minSdkVersion to 21 in manifest
- Set targetSdkVersion to 21 in manifest
- Set taget framework to Android 5.0 in project settings
- Cleaned and rebuilt project

The error is still there :-(
Are there other settings required to make this work?

Comment: do you have created a colorPrimary value in your color xml file?

Comment: Did you try `android:colorPrimary`?

Comment: Ha, that did the trick :-)

Comment: Please share the solution ^_^

Comment: Sure, see my answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what worked for my project.

In `res/values-v21/styles.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In `res/values/styles.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should follow the convention directly from the Material Design documentation(https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette):

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

What you are missing here is the `android:` namespace prefix to the `colorPrimary` item. Because of this, it cannot find the respective attribute as it's not defined in the scope.

Otherwise you would need to remove the `android:` prefix from the theme

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the colors used in styles.xml where not defined. 
So,make sure u have defined all the colors as well as names properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it were wrong entries in the SDK from an external partner i use:

- they had style information in the SDK value.xml file
- they also hat an android:theme part in their AndroidManifest.xml

which both are obviously not nessesary when you build an SDK (and not an app, where you need config about the themes and colors...)

Answer (score 0):

The major issue people will face this because they forgot to add android before defining the colors
And
The defined colors not exists in your colors xml

`<item name="android:colorPrimary">#fff</item>
 <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#fff</item>
 <item name="android:colorAccent">#fff</item>`

Here I have defined colors directly if you use `@color/color_primary` like this the mentioned color_primary must exist in your color file.

Answer (score -2):

What you are doing is declare that the colorPrimary of your style is the colorPrimary of your style... What does not have sense.

You should declare wich color is:

```
<style name="_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">#6c0e54</item>
```

If you want to define another colors and the call it on the style create a xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
     <color name="apptheme_color1">#9D3F86</color>
     <color name="apptheme_color2">#84226C</color>
  </resources>
```

and then you can do:

```
 <style name="_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/apptheme_color1</item>
```

Comment: Nope? I'm referring to a color from my colors.xml

Comment: Edited on how to declare and call the color

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Even your first suggestion produces the same error... The problem is not that the color is not found, but the attribute colorPrimary.

Comment: try `parent="Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"` instead of `parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Answer (score -3):

Add this code in `res\values\colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

Now sync your project.

Comment: OP didn't want to simply hard code values, they wanted to read `colorPrimary` from their colors.xml, and derive the other two colors from that.

Comment: Suggest some generic way to solve the problem please.